# How to fix Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user this error in the system android application?

Tags: android, android-source

In the settings application I'm trying to receive message about changing network status.
It looks like this:

```
 <receiver android:name="com.android.settings.NetworkStateReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
        </intent-filter>
 </receiver>



public class NetworkStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
  public static final String TAG = "NetworkStateReceiver";
  public static final String NETWORK_CHANGED_ACTION = "com.android.settings.NetworkStateReceiver.NETWORK_CHANGED";

  @Override
  public void onReceive( Context context, Intent intent )
  {
      Log.d(TAG, "Network state changed");
      Intent i = new Intent();
      i.setAction(NETWORK_CHANGED_ACTION);
      context.sendBroadcast(i);
  }
}
```

From this receiver I'm trying to send message to DeviceInfoFragment, there is receiver, which should catch this broadcast:

```
 private BroadcastReceiver mNetwrokStateReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.d("NetworkStateReceiver_DEVICE_INFO", "network state changed");
        if (isNetworkConnected()) {
            Log.d("NetworkStateReceiver_DEVICE_INFO", "network connected");
            mHelpPreference.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            mHelpPreference.setEnabled(false);
            Log.d("NetworkStateReceiver_DEVICE_INFO", "network disconnected");
        }
    }
};
```

I register it in onResume and unregister in onPause.

But I got error in **NetworkStateReceiver** in this line:

```
context.sendBroadcast(i);
```

Calling a method in the system process without a qualified user

Is there is any way to fix it?

Answer (score 5):

It is just a warning.

You can see that by looking at the source code:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/b267554/core/java/android/app/ContextImpl.java

Just search for the method "warnIfCallingFromSystemProcess()"

Comment: Thank you for your insightful answer. It's unfortunate there seems to be no way to suppress the warning and maintain the system uid for additional privileges. Nor any documentation as to why it's a warning in the first place for system apps. It's odd.

Answer (score 5):

If you are developing market applications you cannot eliminate this warning.

If you are a handset vendor, you can add to your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS"/>
```

and then can send the broadcast as an actual user.

```
context.sendBroadcastAsUser(i, new UserHandle(UserHandle.USER_CURRENT));
```

The application that is launched will get elevated permissions only if it is properly configured to do so.

Comment: And what about if you're using 'startActivity' or 'startService'? These methods don't have a '*asUser' counterpart...

Comment: @GuilhermeSantos Context provides startActivityAsUser and startServiceAsUser, but again these are for handset vendors and are not available to 3rd party app developers. If you are publishing an app using Android Studio you cannot suppress these warnings. The only solution is to find an implementation that does not broadcast Intents to get the required behavior.